# Android: How do I make a ListView update itself periodically?

Tags: android, listview, refresh, auto-update

I never got this working in a straightforward manner. Sorry if I'm being a little vague. I'll try to elaborate on what I'm trying to do. I am trying to build a listview that grabs its data from a webservice. Once I initialize a listview, I want to keep polling the webserver periodically and update the contents of the listview. For this I am doing something like this:

```
public class SampleAutoUpdateList extends Activity {

     //Autoupdate handler
     private Handler handler = new Handler();
     private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

       /*
        * Update the list 
        */

       try {
          Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");
          searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);
          searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          handler.postDelayed(this, Configuration.REFRESH_INTERVAL);
       } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", e.getMessage());
       }

      }

     };

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.linearmode);
      this.context = this;

      searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);
      LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondaryLayout);
      ListView list = new ListView(context);
      l2.addView(list);
      // display UI
      UpdateDisplay(list);
      updater.run();
     }

     private SearchAdapter getFeed(String URL) {
        try
        {
            SearchHandler handler = new SearchHandler();

            URL url = new URL(URL);

            String data = convertStreamToString(url.openStream());
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf('['), data.length()-1);
                    handler.parseJSON(data);

            return handler.getFeed();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            // if we have a problem, simply return null
            Log.e("getFeed", ee.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDisplay(View searchView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        searchList = (ListView) searchView;

        myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,       
                "Please wait...", "Loading search....", true); 

        new Thread() { 
            public void run() { 
                try{ 

                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                } catch (Exception e) {  } 

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 

                        if (searchAdapter == null)
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", "No Feed Available");
                            return;
                        }

                        searchAdapter.setContext(context);
                        searchList.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                        searchList.setSelection(0);
                    } 
                }); 

                // Dismiss the Dialog 
                myProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
            } 
        }.start(); 
    }
}
```

And the SearchHandler class is simple:

```
public class SearchHandler  extends DefaultHandler {
    SearchAdapter _adapter;
    SearchItem _item;

    public SearchHandler()
    {
    }

    public SearchAdapter getFeed()
    {
        return _adapter;
    }

    public void parseJSON(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _adapter = new SearchAdapter();
        JSONArray parseArray;
        try {
            parseArray = new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i=0; i < parseArray.length(); i++) {

                SearchItem item = new SearchItem();

                JSONObject jsonUser = parseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item.set_from(jsonUser.getString ("from"));
                item.set_msg(jsonUser.getString("msg"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, the handler gets called and the new items are fetched, but the list is never refreshed... Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Could you consider adding a few paragraphs to explain, in greater detail, what it is you are trying to accomplish? That will help people give you answers.

Comment: Sorry about that... Just updated my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is a little bit difficult to follow your code, since you only have a fragment of it, and few of the really relevant bits. For example, based on your available code, your list should be forever empty, since you never associate the `searchAdapter` with a `ListView`...at least in the code you have shown.

That being said, the following lines seem particularly odd:

```
        searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);
        searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I am going to assume that `getFeed()` (not shown) creates a new `ListAdapter` of some sort. If `getFeed()` is creating a new `ListAdapter`, there is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it, as its data set hasn't changed -- it's brand new. Moreover, unless you are associating this new `ListAdapter` to your `ListView`, the new `ListAdapter` will have no effect.

If I'm barking up the wrong tree, consider adding lines to your sample showing the implementation of `getFeed()` and where you are using `searchAdapter`.

Comment: Sorry again.. I was just thinking that if the posted is huge, no one will bother to look at it. But now I realize that, the part I skipeed is the most important.. Updated with all relevant parts...

Comment: OK, well, then, I think my answer is accurate. Your SearchHandler creates new adapters each time. However, I only see you associating the adapter with the ListView once, in UpdateDisplay(). Hence, the second and subsequent adapters are just created and discarded, near as I can tell.

Comment: Hmm.. For some reason, I never expected this to be a problem. So do I re-associate it with the ListView everytime or do you suggest any other method?

Comment: Well, there are two approaches. First, you could update your existing SearchAdapter in-place, using notifyDataSetChanged() to trigger the ListView update. Since I don't think you have the SearchAdapter code posted, I don't know if that will be easy or difficult. Second, you could call setAdapter() on the ListView every time you build a new adapter.

Comment: The second one seemed the easiest to try first so I made the listview "list" into a global declaration and tried accessing it from the handler, list.setAdapter(searchAdapter); and it keeps throwing a NullPointerException at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java). I'm currently seeing what's wrong here... Will get back soon if it works...

Comment: Great... As always... you're the expert when it comes to typical problems like this.. Thank You!!